# Django Rest Framework browsable API breaks when changing the port

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently developing my first app with DRF and I'm pretty impressed by it and the browsable API it has build in. However, when I change the port where I host my application (both in `manage.py` aswell as in the `runserver` command), all the buttons stop working. I can still click on links to make sure resources where created, but that's about it. I also can't log in and the POST forms don't appear, which is really the most annoying part. Moreover, when I change the port back to the default 8000, it's still broken.

Don't really know if I can post an example of this. It doesn't seem to depend on anything in the actual code. It just happens when I change the port.

Comment: what did you do to change the port? `python manage.py runserver 1234`? or else

Comment: What was your changed port number?, Can you please add the error message or warning message if any shown in terminal.

Comment: this happens when you change port.

Comment: @AvenDesta Yes and I also changed the BACKEND_API_URL in Settings.py

Comment: @AravindaKS I changed it to 8100. There was no error message. Although I also have to say that my browser console is broken with this project, so there might be error messages and I'm just not seeing them.

Comment: @ShahVipul Well I kinda found that out on my own. The problem is: When I change the port back it's still there.

Comment: port back it's still there there you got an issue.

Comment: @TigersEye120 time to delete the post. its no useful if it appears on stackoverflow search

Comment: @AvenDesta Why would I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

So while I don't know what exactly caused it, a CTRL-reload has fixed it for now. Still pops up from time to time.